# How do I remove just the current instance of the array, not all instances of the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I remove just the current instance of the array, not all instances of the array?

```
var persons = [];

showAllButton.onclick = function() {

  while (showList.firstChild)showList.removeChild(showList.firstChild);
```

Created new node instances.

```
  for (var l in persons) {
    var listNode = document.createElement("LI");
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.innerHTML = "Remove";
    showList.appendChild(listNode);
    showList.appendChild(btn);
```

Displays pushed instances correctly.

```
    listNode.innerHTML =
    '<p><b>Full Name:</b> ' + persons[l].firstName +' ' + persons[l].lastName + '</p>' +
    '<p><b>Phone:</b> ' + persons[l].phone + '</p>' +
    '<p><b>Address:</b> ' + persons[l].address + '</p>'
    }
```

Tried a few variations of the following function but just empties the array, or at least wont return the amended array.

```
    btn.onclick = function() {
        var index = Array.indexOf(persons[l]);
        persons.splice(index, 1);              
        return persons;
    }



  if (showAllButton.value=="Show Contacts") {
      showAllButton.value = "Hide Contacts";
      showList.style.display = "block";   
  }


  else if (showAllButton.value = "Hide Contacts") {
      showAllButton.value = "Show Contacts";
      showList.style.display = "none";  
  }
```

}

Comment: have a look at *closures inside for loops*

Comment: `Array.indexOf(persons[l]);` ? What is this supposed to do?

Comment: `else if (showAllButton.value = "Hide Contacts")` will not compare value to string literal, but assign the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably bind l, remove the element at index l, then redraw the dom somehow.:

```
btn.onclick = function(l) { //take over the bound l
    persons.splice(l, 1);              
    //some kind of redraw
    showAllButton.click();
}.bind(null,l);//bind l
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work as expected (sorry, blind coding, have no time to test now)

```
var persons = [];
function removePerson(index) {
    persons.splice(index, 1);
    renderList();
}

function clearList() {
    while (showList.firstChild) {
        showList.removeChild(showList.firstChild);
    }
}

function renderItem(person, index) {
    var item = showList.appendChild(document.createElement("LI"));

    var label = item.appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN"));
    label.innerHTML = persons[i];

    var btn = item.appendChild(document.createElement("BUTTON"));
    btn.innerHRML = "Remove";
    btn.onclick = removePerson.bind(null, index);
}

function renderList() {
    clearList();
    persons.forEach(renderItem);
}
```

Not a kind of best practices, but seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Final Working Code, thank you!

```
showAllButton.onclick = function() {

while (showList.firstChild)showList.removeChild(showList.firstChild);

for (var l in persons) {
var list = showList.appendChild(document.createElement("LI"));
list.innerHTML =
'<p><b>Full Name:</b> ' + persons[l].firstName +' ' + persons[l].lastName + '</p>' +
'<p><b>Phone:</b> ' + persons[l].phone + '</p>' +
'<p><b>Address:</b> ' + persons[l].address + '</p>';

var btn = showList.appendChild(document.createElement("BUTTON"));
btn.innerHTML = "Remove";
btn.onclick = function(l) {
     persons.splice(l, 1);
     showAllButton.click();

}.bind(null,l);

}
```